# Get multiple pages from Google search

Tags: bash, lynx

I'm writing a bash script to get some data from google search.
I used `lynx` for the query and redirect the results into a file for later parsing. The problem is that all I get is one page only, how can I get `lynx` to get the next page / number of pages?

---

I used grep and cut to isolate the URL to be of the kind "www.google.com/search?q=....." but then when I try to resend it to lynx it doesn't open the next page, just shows the link w/o opening it any suggestion? TNX

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you would need to go through all the links at the bottom of the page, the search results are not condensed in to one single page.

You would need to parse and download each of results by themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I used grep and cut to isolate the URL to be of the kind "www.google.com/search?q=....." but then when I try to resend it to lynx it doesn't open the next page, just shows the link w/o opening it any suggestion? TNX